# C# Как на компьютере подключиться к web камере через wi fi

Tags: c#, wifi, web-camera

> Написал такой код. Но программа видит только устройства, подключенные
> напрямую. Как сделать так, чтобы он подключался к камере через wi fi,
> например через общий роутер(проводов у камеры нет, лишь зарядка)
> Камера уже подключена к роутеру

```
using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;
using System.IO;
using DirectShowLib;
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private VideoCapture capture = null;
        private DsDevice[] webCams = null;
        private int selectedCameraId = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webCams = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            for (int i = 0; i < webCams.Length; i++)
            {
                toolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(webCams[i].Name);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedCameraId = toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        }

        private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (webCams.Length == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Нет доступных камер!");
                }
                else if (toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Необходимо выбрать камеру!");
                }
                else if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    capture = new VideoCapture(selectedCameraId);
                    capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;
                    capture.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mat m = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(m);
                pictureBox1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Horizontal).ToBitmap();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    if (capture != null)
                    {
                        capture.Pause();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.Pause();
                    capture.Dispose();
                    capture = null;
                    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                    selectedCameraId = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mat m = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(m);
                MakeScreenShotForm screenShotForm = new MakeScreenShotForm(m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Horizontal));
                screenShotForm.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```